# Playing omaha showing players hands. Would it be usefull for training purposes?

Tags: software, omaha, training

I am starting to program an omaha software to help users and myself to improve their skills.

I wonder if it would be usefull that my trainer system allows to play offline showing the hands of all players.

Do you think it would be usefull for novices to avoid playing secondary hands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I've done the same thing in a live game to get a feel for how strong your starting hands really are.

It would be good to repeat the same exercise with different table sizes.

Comment: Thay you for your feed. I think I will do it, aswell as exercises for odds just for your hand at different streets. Maybe I will allow the user to show his % of winning chances and also for the hands showed by the other players/bots.